# how to reverse engineer c++ project?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, uml

as asked above.

cheers in advance

Comment: Theresonly1, your answer is getting closed because it doesn't provide enough information. What have you got? What do you want? Source code from a binary? (No chance.) Understanding of the program's architecture from the obfuscated sources? Provide more information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Examine the assembler code.
2. Turn it back into C++.
3. Profit.

Admittedly, there a fair bit of detail you could add to steps 1 and 2 but that's the basic idea, and the level of detail in my answer more than match the level of detail in your question :-)